# $elemMatch and update

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I would like to update a subdocument that was fetched using $elemMatch. I've found some posts online but so far I am not able to get it to work. This is what I have:

Schema:

```
var user = {
  _id: ObjectId
  addresses: [{
    _id: ObjectId
    street: String
  }]
};
```

Code:

```
this.findOne({
  'addresses._id': address_id
}, { 'occurrences': { $elemMatch: {
   '_id': address_id
 }}})
  .exec(function(err, doc) {
    if (doc) {
      // Update the sub doc
      doc.addresses[0].street = 'Blah';

      doc.update({ 'addresses': { $elemMatch: { '_id': address_id }}}, { $set: {"addresses.$.street": doc.addresses[0].street }})
        .exec(function(err, count) {
          ...
```

The above results in the address sub doc to be wiped out and a blank new one recreated.  How can I save the doc/subdoc?

My goal is to be able to fetch a document (user) by subdocument (addresses) ID, modify that one matching address then save it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do this all with a single `update` call on the model instead of fetching it first with `findOne`:

```js
User.update(
  {'addresses._id': address_id},
  {$set: {'addresses.$.street': 'Blah'}},
  function(err, count) { ... });
```

This uses the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#up._S_) in the `$set` to target just the `addresses` element that was matched in the query.

Comment: won't this be updating if there are multiple objects.

Comment: This is dangerous as @kailashyogeshwar says. If there are multiple elements in the street array, they will all be updated.

Comment: @ogborstad No, the `$` in the update targets only the `addresses` element with an `_id` that matches `address_id` as that's part of the query.

Comment: How we can edit this so, it push into array when the condition doesn't match.