# Mongoose Find and Update Document in Array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am building a voting method in my application.  This is my schema:

```
var Poll = new Schema({
    name: String,
    descriptionString: String,
    options: [{
        optionName: String,
        optionNumber: Number,
        numberOfVotes: Number
    }],
    creator: String,
    whoVoted: []
});
```

I want to use findAndUpdate to increment `numberOfVotes` given the `Poll` `_id` and `option` `_id`.

I can find the Poll using this:

```
Polls.findOne({_id:req.body.pollID})
```

If the `_id` is unique for each of the options in the database could I just use this? This isn't working.

```
Polls.findOneAndUpdate({"options._id": req.body.optionID},{ $inc: { "options.numberOfVotes": 1 }})
```

Comment: Exactly similar question has been answered here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25577029/elemmatch-and-update

Comment: Why isnt it working? What error are you getting?